# Hierarchical Structures Database Select By Lambda Expression

Tags: c#, sql, lambda

Hierarchical Structures  Database Select  By Lambda Expression 
Hi My Table Structure is recursive

ID

ParentID

UserGROUPNAME

[image]

How Can I select Subset an Id   from my contex By Lambda Expression  like this

[image]

I Try to select first

var keys = db.UsersGroups.Select(x => x).Where(u => u.GroupMasterID == 1).ToArray();

var UsersGroup = db.UsersGroups.Where(x => keys.Contains(x.GroupMasterID));

But I think it's return wrong or return  just 2 level data

Please Help me

Comment: Joe Celco has an interesting solution to this problem called the Adjacency List Model.   http://www.ibase.ru/devinfo/DBMSTrees/sqltrees.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally I create a sql function

like this

```
Create  FUNCTION [dbo].[GET_USERGROUPLIST]
(
    @GROUPID INT
)
RETURNS  TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(
    WITH UsersGroups_CTE AS (
SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[UsersGroups]
WHERE ID = @GROUPID
UNION ALL
SELECT e.ID, e.GroupName, e.ParentID ,e.Status
FROM [dbo].[UsersGroups] e
INNER JOIN UsersGroups_CTE ucte ON ucte.ID = e.ParentID
)
SELECT *
FROM UsersGroups_CTE Where UsersGroups_CTE.Status = 1
);
```

and Next Use in my model like this

```
db.GET_USERGROUPLIST(1);
```

Many Thanks to lontivero for him suggestion

Answer (score 0):

That´s something that you cannot do, without mess it up, with linq. What you have to do is to flatten the hierarchy using a probably a [common table expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) and then you will be able to write a simple linq query.

Comment: Hi lontivero ...  How Can I Use CTE In Lambda can you please show me one example

Comment: Create an sql view using CTE as the article does. Then perform the query against that flatten view. The magic is not in Linq but in flatten the hierarchy, that's all.